# How to make a slideshow with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm a beginner with javascript. I've been wanting to make a slideshow for my website but have been stuck for quite some time now.

I have some code that is working perfectly over here : [JSfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/446/)

```
// Code In Fiddles
function Divs() {
    var divs= $('#parent div'),
        now = divs.filter(':visible'),
        next = now.next().length ? now.next() : divs.first(),
        speed = 1000;

    now.fadeOut(speed);
    next.fadeIn(speed);
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(Divs, 3400);
});
```

But not so much here: [JSfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/yfmpuyfh/1/)

The code is exactly the same in both fiddles, one works, the other does not.

The code is not working on my website either, so I wondered what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `jquery` plugin to get that javascript to work. [Get Jquery Here](https://jquery.com).

You can also use a hosted library to get jquery into your project. Hosted library are great because many developers use them which means website viewers will most likely have them cached in their browsers which reduces load time.

[Check out the hosted libraries here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

**Example library**

```
// post this in the head of you html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep in mind to do that in the future!